# How to recover the lost git file after git-stash pop

Tags: git, github, recovery, git-stash

I had 2 branches. I recently did `git stash` on first branch and then moved to different branch. I made few changes in the second branch. And i wanted to move to the first branch so I did `git stash` again in my second branch and moved to first branch. 
But after i did `git stash pop` it merged few files and i lost all my changes after the previous commit. The got the following message after git stash pop

`git stash pop
 Auto-merging src/settings.jsx
 CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in src/settings.jsx
 Auto-merging public/css/index.css`

I expect to recover all the files that i lost after `git stash pop`
I'm new to git. Any help would be mch appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you do git status and see which files are present?

Comment: Are you sure you "popped" the right stash state .... do a `git stash list` to see the sorting of your stashes. You maybe applied a wrong stash state to your branch. You may apply it then with e.g., `git stash apply stash@{2}`. `git stash pop` just pops the latest stashed state ... if you stashed on the other branch, maybe you applied the wrong one.

Comment: To undo/restore changes you may have a look at `git reflog`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pop will simply return you only last git stash files. So here is what you should do-

1. Get the list of all stashes :

```
$ git stash list
```

It will return you something like :

```
stash@{0}: WIP on develop: 049d071 added the index file
stash@{1}: WIP on develop: j264053 Revert "added file_size"
stash@{2}: WIP on develop: 21t80a4 added number to log
```

2. Now you can apply whichever stash you want to apply:

```
git stash apply stash@{2}
```

Or

```
git stash apply 2
```

Apply will not remove your stash like pop so you can still revisit it later.

Comment: I had tried git stash list and then `git stash apply stash@{1}` but it was giving me an error. I tried the following:
`git stash list
stash@{0}: WIP on range-slider: 7ca64b9 remove tests from commit hook
stash@{1}: WIP on radiobutton: c15e246 WIP: radiobutton test-cases `

` git stash apply stash@{1}
unknown option: -encodedCommand `

Comment: Are you using some option (-encodedCommand) while applying git stash ?

Comment: No. I resolved the issue by using 
" `git stash apply 2` "
I recovered the lost file, But a new file which i had created in a different branch got merged in this branch after `git stash apply`

Comment: Great ! Yes you can use that too.

Comment: Nice, you wrote as an answer what I was commenting above, but this does not answer the question, as the question is "How to recover the lost git file after git-stash pop"